# Convert class object to Java RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a pojo- AnalyticsModel and I have a loop where I create object for the pojo. Each time I create the object, I'm saving to a list called AnalyticsModelList. And then after coming out of the loop, I'm converting the list to an RDD. Below is my code:

```
do {    
       AnalyticsModel analyticsObj = new AnalyticsModel(time, columnName, aggrResult);
       analyticsList.add(analyticsObj);
    }while (cal.getTimeInMillis() <= endDate);

    JavaRDD<AnalyticsModel> analyticsRdd = sc.parallelize(analyticsList);
```

Instead of adding to a list and then converting it to an RDD, is there anyway I can directly have the object as an RDD. Can someone please guide me though this ? I'm pretty new to Spark.

Thanks

Comment: its looks good this is a better way just use `Kyro serializer` and job will be much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way. But **what you are doing works just fine if you have few `AnalyticsModel` objects**(You don't have to make your life complex by the following solution).
If you are going to create a huge number of `AnalyticsModel` objects then consider below solution.

This class generates one `AnalyticsModel` instance per call.

```
public class AnalyticsModelGenerator implements FlatMapFunction<String, AnalyticsModel> {

    private final Long endDate;
    private final Calendar cal;

    public AnalyticsModelGenerator(Calendar cal, Long endDate) {
        this.cal = cal;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterable<AnalyticsModel> call(String dummyInput) throws Exception {
        return new Iterable<AnalyticsModel>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<AnalyticsModel> iterator() {
                return new AMIterator(cal, endDate);
            }
        }
    }

    private class AMIterator implements Iterator<AnalyticsModel> {
        private final Long endDate;
        private final Calendar cal;

        public AMIterator(Calendar cal, Long endDate) {
            this.cal = cal;
            this.endDate = endDate;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (cal.getTimeInMillis() <= endDate);
        }

        @Override
        public AnalyticsModel next() {
            return new AnalyticsModel(time, columnName, aggrResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Below code creates an RDD of `AnalyticsModel` objects:

```
JavaRDD<String> initJavaRDD = jSparkContext.parallelize(new ArrayList<String>(){{add("dummyInput");}});
JavaRDD<AnalyticsModel> amJavaRDD = initJavaRDD.flatMap(new AnalyticsModelGenerator(cal, endDate));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I could not quite follow the below code:
JavaRDD<String> initJavaRDD = jSparkContext.parallelize(new ArrayList<String>(){{add("dummyInput");}}); 
I think I have come up with a simpler solution, which I have posted below

Comment: It creates a new RDD with one dummy string that will not be used anywhere and then the flatMap creates as many`AnalyticsModel` objects as you require.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This solution looks good, but unfortunately I cannot use this in my code, as I'm using Spark 1.6 where the call function returns Iterable  and not Iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. This is working fine for me :)